# How to convert SqlDataReader to LINQ way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I wonder how to convert SqlDataReader to LINQ way?

Here is my SqlDataReader code.

```
string strConn = "server=xxx.com;database=mydb;User ID=test;Password=test;Trusted_Connection=true;";
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
myConn.Open();

string strSQL = "select period from timetable_view where identity_num = '" + Identity_NUM + "' week = '3'";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn);
SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

int Count = Add_CourseConfirmedQuery.Count();

Random rnum = new Random();
string[] arr = new string[Count];
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    myDataReader.Read();
    arr[i] = myDataReader["period"].ToString();
}
ViewBag.test = arr[0];
ViewBag.test2 = arr[1];

myCommand.Cancel();
myDataReader.Close();
myConn.Close();
myConn.Dispose();

string[] input2 = new string[Count];

for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    input2[i] = arr[i];
}
```

This code works fine.

I've tried to code in LINQ but it doesn't work.

Here's the LINQ code that I've tried, but I have no idea how to extract all records of `a.identity_num`, and put them into an array like the code above(SqlDataReader).

```
var test = from a in timetable_view
           where a.identity_num = Identity_NUM && a.week = "3"
           select a new{a.identity_num};

ViewBag.test = test.FirstOrDefault();
```

**[UPDATE Question]**

This is what I am trying now.

I can't extract the right records from my table.

**But the page display: System.String[]**

```
var Query = from m in db.members
            join d in db.departments on m.department equals d.department_id
            join s in db.select_list on m.member_id equals s.member_id
            join c in db.courses on s.kkk_id equals c.kkk_id
            join t in db.teachers on c.teacher equals t.teacher_id
            where m.identity_num == Identity_NUM && c.week == "3"
            select c.period;
            var PA = Query.ToArray();
            int Count = Query.Count();


string[] arr = new string[Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = PA.ToString();
            }
            ViewBag.test = arr[0];
            ViewBag.test2 = arr[1];
.............
............
...........

string[] input2 = new string[Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
         {
            input2[i] = arr[i];
         }
.............
............
...........
```

Comment: What do you need that annonymus type for?
If you don't need it, change the new { c.period } to c.period

Comment: @CSharpie But the page display: System.String[]

Comment: There is no but, System.String[] is not an annonymus type, or ist it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated to match changed question:

Don't select a new anonymous object, just select the value:

```
var arr= (from a in timetable_view
           where a.identity_num = Identity_NUM && a.week = "3"
           select a.period).ToArray();
```

Fully updated change should be

```
var Query = from m in db.members
            join d in db.departments on m.department equals d.department_id
            join s in db.select_list on m.member_id equals s.member_id
            join c in db.courses on s.kkk_id equals c.kkk_id
            join t in db.teachers on c.teacher equals t.teacher_id
            where m.identity_num == Identity_NUM && c.week == "3"
            select c.period;


var arr = Query.ToArray();    

ViewBag.test = arr[0];
ViewBag.test2 = arr[1];
```

From the comments:

- The error message generated by having ToString() in the code indicates to us that period is a string anyhow and so the call can be removed.
- To get count, `int Count = arr.Length`
- The for-loop has been removed because it is redundant, using the ToArray() function achieves the same result.

Comment: I've updated my question. But the page display: <>f__AnonymousType15`1[System.String][]

Comment: @user2401077 Check the updated answer.  Also if you are only going to use the first two values you might want to use `var arr = Query.Take(2).ToArray()`

Comment: Why do you delete the for loop?

Comment: And also I still need int Count = Query.Count();

Comment: Then do int Count = arr.Length;
Your for-loop became obsolete. All you need is the variable 'arr'. Its an array of strings. More precise arr is System.String[].

Comment: ERROR message: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Comment: @CSharpie Thanks for answering, I was on lunch. Yes, the for-loop is obsolete because `ToArray()` is basically doing the same thing.

Comment: @user2401077 The Error message now tells us the period is a string and so the ToString() is uncessary, just remove it.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert linq query to array. Bellow code should do this:

```
var test = (from a in school_timetable_view
           where a.identity_num == Identity_NUM && a.week == "3"
           select a new{a.identity_num}).ToArray();
```

Comment: That creates an anonymous type rather that selecting the value like the reader code does.  Also the reader code is grabbing period not identity_num

Comment: I've updated my question. But the page display: <>f__AnonymousType15`1[System.String][]

Comment: Those `=` need to be `==`, also.

Answer (score 0):

you should need to convert linkq to toArray:

```
var TEST = (from a in timetable_view
           where a.identity_num = Identity_NUM && a.week = "3"
           select a new{a.identity_num}).ToArray();

var Query = from m in db.members
            join d in db.departments on m.department equals d.department_id
            join s in db.select_list on m.member_id equals s.member_id
            join c in db.courses on s.kkk_id equals c.kkk_id
            join t in db.teachers on c.teacher equals t.teacher_id
            where m.identity_num == Identity_NUM && c.week == "3"
            select c.period.ToString();


var arr = Query.ToArray();    

ViewBag.test = arr[0];
ViewBag.test2 = arr[1];
```

Comment: I've updated my question. But the page display: <>f__AnonymousType15`1[System.String][]

Comment: Why do you delete the for loop? And also I still need int Count = Query.Count();